# I have one subsub category in magento and I want to display all its parent categories

Tags: magento, parent-child

I have category tree. Cat1 : (id=2), Cat1-sub(ID=3), Cat1-sub-sub(id=4) and Cat2 (id=5)
Now if update category Cat-sub-sub, I want to show all it's parent category ids as well. e.g 3,2 both.

Answer (score 3):

I think, from your question, that you want to get the parent category ids for a given category  If so then, you can use the following to get the ids:

```
 $category->getParentIds()
```

alternatively you can get thea actual models by:

```
$category->getParentCategories()
```

If this is not the issue then please clarify things in your question.